# How to parse Spring Boot's backend ResponseEntity response in JS/VueJS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

Before I had the controller that returned the Object itself:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public HelloObj getHelloObj() {
     return new HelloObj("Hello");
  }
}

public class HelloObj {
   private String value;
   
   public HelloObj(String value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   // getter/setter
}
```

In my VueJs I got this response and parsed it into an object like this (it is a websocket handler method):

```
getHello(payload) {
  let helloObj = JSON.parse(payload.body);
  console.log(helloObj.value);
}
```

I modified my backend in a way that it returns a ResponseEntity now:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public ResponseEntity<HelloObj> getHelloObj() {
     return new ResponseEntity<>(new HelloObj("Hello"), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to parse this response in my VueJS project. My question is how do I need to modify this code:

```
getHello(payload) {
  let helloObj = JSON.parse(payload.body);
  console.log(helloObj.value);
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? What does `payload.body` now contain? What is the difference in the body compared to before??

Comment: `payload.body` looks like: `{"headers":{},"body":{"value": "Hello"},"statusCode": "OK","statusCodeValue":200}` -> This is what should be converted to a body that is only: {"value": "Hello"} and use the object like: `<h2> {{ helloObj.value }}` </h2>

Comment: I made a workaround that works although I hate it: `let myString = payload.body.substring(payload.body.indexOf("body")+6, payload.body.indexOf("statusCode")-2); let myObject = JSON.parse(myString);`